# How to show the number of items from database according to drop down menu number in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to django. I have 100 items in database, and i have dropdown menu number [1,5,10,20]. if i select 20 then i would like to show 20 items with 5 different pages.

if i select 10, i would like to show 10 items in one page with 10 different pages in django.

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how to do that.

I have no idea how to do it. I made HTML drop down menu with number, but how can i connect it to database, and populate and show it?

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
```

Comment: You need a `<select>` tag around all that.  The select tag will be sent in a POST request just like your other `<input>` fields, using its `name` attribute.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I show items from this using Django? <select id =“length” method=“post”>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
</select>

Comment: There are a lot of pieces, and we don't know what you have.  You need your Django code to send an HTML form that includes the `<select>`.  When the user send it back, then you'll read the value from the form.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a form and put `<select></select>` tag inside.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="myselect">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

In your views.py, you can add

```
def myviews(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      myselect = request.POST.get('myselect')
      # use myselect to fetch data from the database.
```

`myselect` will hold value which can be used to fetch data from the database and then you can return data to your templates.

For database set up [refer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial02/).

For pagination please [refer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/pagination/).